# Cancel form submitting after checking database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I would like to submit a form only after checking if some of the inputs are not already existing in the database.

I use beforeSend for checking if there are some fabrics to add, if so, I create a variable with all the fabrics name, and my php script "check_fabric.php" controls if the fabrics are not already in the database.

I would like to submit the form **only if** the fabrics name are new.

```
$("#addorder").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form, event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $("#addorder");
        var id_customer = $("#id_customer").val();

        $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: form.serialize()+"&id_customer="+id_customer,
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {

                        $("#submit-btn").removeClass("effet add").addClass("sending").val('Adding....').attr('disabled',true);


                        var nbfabric = $("#nbfabric").val();
                        if(nbfabric>0)  {

                            var arrayFabric = new Array();

                            for (var i=0;i<nbfabric;i++) {

                                arrayFabric.push($('input[name="fabric_'+i+'"]').val());
                            }
                            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arrayFabric);

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "post",
                                url: "check_fabric.php",
                                data: {data : jsonString},
                                success: function (data) {

                                    if (data === "ok") {
                                        form.submit();
                                    } else {
                                        alert(data);//data lists all the fabrics name already existing in the database
                                        $("#submit-btn").removeClass("sending").addClass("effet ajout").val('Ajouter').attr('disabled',false);
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    },

                    success: function(data) {
                        form.fadeOut("normal", function(){
                            $("#return_message").html(data).fadeIn();
                        });
                    },
                    }
                });
      }
});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `xhr.abort();` where u wanna stop

Comment: Why not make this a little less complex. Just submit whatever you are collecting from use and if there is an issue, report an error code/message Rather than all this overly complex stuff

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think that it's better to put the whole code for better understanding

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I've already tried it, but it still sends the form.

Comment: Totally agree with @RiggsFolly - this is overcomplicated. Just send the request to your backend and check whatever you need in there, why use 2 AJAX calls?